# How to Convert Dask Series DataFrame to Dask Array

Tags: python, dask, series, dask-dataframe

I am dealing with a `.snappy.parquet` file extension and successfully read it using `dask.dataframe.read_parquet()`. I set the partition so that I will be having a partition composed of ten rows of data at a time. Here is the code implementation that I used.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
train_path = ["/train.snappy.parquet"]
data = dd.read_parquet(train_path, engine="pyarrow", compression = "snappy", 
                       columns = "X_jets", split_row_groups=10)
```

When I returned `data`, it gave me this:

```
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=21556
    object
       ...
     ...  
       ...
       ...
Name: X_jets, dtype: object
Dask Name: getitem, 2 graph layers
```

From this information, it can be inferred that I am dealing with a tensor composed of two numpy arrays. Each numpy array is an image with a size of `125x125`. My question then is, how do I load this dask series structure so that I will see arrays? I used `data.compute()` but its been five hours now and its still running, so I terminated the process. This approach I think is wrong. I am also hoping to convert it to dask array for parallel processing. Any insights on this problem? Can this problem be solved using dask in the first place? Also, I am dealing with an extremely huge file, so reading it with pandas directly will not help as it will return an OOM (Out Of Memory) error. Thank you for your time.

Edit: I looked at dask.dataframe.Series.compute [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.compute.html) and just the dask.dataframe.Series [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.Series.html). I am thinking of reading the file first as `data = dd.read_parquet()` and then apply `data.Series.compute()`. I applied it but the problem still persist.

**EDIT**: I wanted to preprocess the data first, so I did

```
from dask_ml.preprocessing import StandardScaler #Scale to zero mean and unit variance

train_path = ["\filename.train.snappy.parquet"]
data = dd.read_parquet(train_path, engine="pyarrow", compression = "snappy")
X = data["X_jets"].astype("float32")
y = data["y"]
def xjets_preprocess(image_data):
    image_data[image_data < 1e-3] = 0.
    image_data[-1,...] = 25.*image_data[-1,...]
    image_data = image_data/100. #Standardize
    data_image = StandardScaler().fit_transform(image_data)
    return data_image
def target(target_data)
    return target_data
```

I have also known lately that you can perform transformations using functions with dask on each partition. So, what I did after is

```
X_images = data.map_partitions(xjets_preprocess, meta=X)
```

I want to implement a resnet model in tensorflow and feed chunks of data into it as it is training. I was thinking to invoke

```
def preprocess_chunk(chunk):
    X_images = chunk["X_jets"].map_partitions(xjets_preprocess, meta=(data["X_jets"], "f8"))
    y = chunk["y"].map_partitions(target, meta=(data["y"], "f8"))
    return X_images, y

#Define some model
model = model
for i in range(0, num_samples, chunk_size):
    chunk = data.loc[i : i + chunk_size]
    X_images, y = preprocess_chunk(chunk)
    X_images = X_images.compute()
    y = y.compute()
    model.train_on_batch(X_images, y, epochs = 1)
```

Comment: *can* you train this model chunkwise? Does it need to be a mutable, persistent object in memory, can it be called in parallel?

Comment: i believe resnet models can be trained chunkwise. i updated the code above.  however, it is till not working for some reason. thus, i am thinking that this is wrong

Answer (score 1):

`compute()` pulls all of your data into memory. If all your data fitted comfortably in memory, you would not need to use dask. Instead, you want to operate on your dask series, so that dask can get on with loading it chunk by chunk upon execution. What is it that you were wanting to actually do with the images?

(and why oh why are they stored in parquet??)

Comment: Hi @mdurant. I updated the post under the edit to describe my aim. And yeah, parquet is the way to go as i received it in that format xD